# Xamarin Forms UWP failing to reference NuGet package System references

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms, nuget-package, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to add a self made NuGet package, built automatically with Visual Studio 2017 to a UWP Xamarin Forms project.

[image: NuGet Package Structure]

However when I try add the package to the UWP package (in VS2017 package manager) it fails.

```
Restoring packages for C:\Development\MyMobile\JobApp\JobApp\JobApp.UWP\project.json...
System.Threading.ThreadPool 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.ThreadPool on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-arm.
System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Thread on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-arm.
System.Diagnostics.Process 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Diagnostics.Process on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-arm.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
System.Threading.ThreadPool 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.ThreadPool on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-arm-aot.
System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Thread on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-arm-aot.
System.Diagnostics.Process 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Diagnostics.Process on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-arm-aot.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
System.Threading.ThreadPool 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.ThreadPool on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64.
System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Thread on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64.
System.Diagnostics.Process 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Diagnostics.Process on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
System.Threading.ThreadPool 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.ThreadPool on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64-aot.
System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Thread on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64-aot.
System.Diagnostics.Process 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Diagnostics.Process on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64-aot.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
System.Threading.ThreadPool 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.ThreadPool on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x86.
System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Thread on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x86.
System.Diagnostics.Process 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Diagnostics.Process on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x86.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
System.Threading.ThreadPool 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.ThreadPool on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x86-aot.
System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Thread on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x86-aot.
System.Diagnostics.Process 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Diagnostics.Process on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x86-aot.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'JobApp.UWP'.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:02.8217814
========== Finished ==========
```

I've edited project.json for the UWP project to try and adding in netstandard1.6 and System.* dependencies, but sadly didn't work.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.3.3",
    "MvvmLight": "5.3.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "10.0.2",
    "Xamarin.Forms": "2.3.4.231",
    "System.Threading": "4.3.0",
    "System.Runtime": "4.3.0",
    "System.Diagnostics.Process": "4.3.0",
    "System.Threading.Thread": "4.3.0",
    "System.Threading.ThreadPool": "4.3.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {
      "imports": "netstandard1.6"
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

Why is UWP having problems with System.* references?

Here is the NuSpec for my package;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>MyCommon</id>
        <version>1.0.131</version>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <dependencies>
            <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.6">
                <dependency id="Quartz" version="3.0.0-alpha2" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
                <dependency id="ImageSharp" version="1.0.0-alpha5-00046" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
                <dependency id="System.ComponentModel" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
            </group>
            <group targetFramework=".NETStandard1.6">
                <dependency id="Quartz" version="3.0.0-alpha2" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
                <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
                <dependency id="ImageSharp" version="1.0.0-alpha5-00046" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
                <dependency id="System.ComponentModel" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
            </group>
        </dependencies>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: Could you provide  `.nuspec` file ?

Comment: Revised my question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your NuGet package is referencing `Quartz 3.0.0-alpha2`, which references `System.Threading.Thread` and `System.Threading.ThreadPool`.

These two packages (`System.Threading.Thread` and `System.Threading.ThreadPool`) are not supported on Universal Windows Platform, at least not at this moment.

[Here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/34#issuecomment-265550749), Immo Landwerth (program manager on the .NET team) says:

> - UWP currently only supports .NET Standard 1.4
> - Our goal is to
>     eventually extend UWP to also implement .NET Standard 2.0. Once that
>     happens, UWP will also support `Thread`.

Here are some GitHub issues where you can read more about this topic:

- [quartznet - Windows 10 Project support](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/442),
- [dotnet/corefx - `System.Threading.Thread` should support all runtimes](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2576),
- [dotnet/standard - Why are we including `System.Threading.Thread` in .NET Standard?](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/34), and
- a [pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/13569https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/13569) that indicates that they are working on UWP support for `System.Threading.Thread`.

Comment: Very informative, thank you! UWP not supporting .NET Standard 1.6 is frustrating, means our Windows Mobile support will be delayed.